# Can JavaScript data within HTML also be crawled?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, javascript

I'm curious about Amazon's website, it doesn't have HTML and instead most of it is in JavaScript:

[image]

I have a Nuxt SSR app, and the `window.__NUXT__` script is very huge and my fetched data is also in there.

I'm wondering if I can put my fetched data inside `<no-ssr>` tags to optimize my HTML load but it will be removed in my HTML `<body>` and only visible on JavaScript, the same as with Amazon.

Is that OK to do, or will that affect my SEO?

Comment: best idea is to test it. The Mobile Friendly Test will give you a visual on what Googlebot sees as well as gives you the rendered html it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Usually according to google statement, there shouldn't be any hidden content. JS working at backend was a big issue as it create different content on front side.

But now advancement in AI and ML google algorithms are able to read JS and images also.

So just make sure your code work fine and do not create any issue.

Even google recommending it's own architecture on Angular JS.  So this will work perfectly fine.